# Why aren't union member data default-initialized?

Tags: c++, class, initialization, unions

AFAIK a class/struct/union that doesn't initialize its member data int the constructor-initializer-list, then they are default-initialized. If a member data is of built-int integral type then it has an indeterminate value. If it is of a class type then its default-ctor is invoked (accessible and non-deleted default-ctor is required).

Here is my example:

```
struct A{
    A(){std::cout << "A()\n";}
    A(int){std::cout << "A(int)\n";}
    A(A const&){std::cout << "A(A const&)\n";}
    ~A(){std::cout << "~A()\n";}
    A& operator = (A const& ){std::cout << "=(Aconst&)\n"; return *this;}
};

struct B{
    B(int){std::cout << "B(int)\n";} // a_ and d_ are default-init
    double d_;
    A a_;
};

B b = 10;
```

The output:

```
A()
B(int)
~A()
```

- It is OK so the constructor `B(int)` doesn't initialize the members `d_` and `a_` in its ctor-init list explicitly so they are default-init. `d_` has an undefined value. While `a_` is default-init.

Until here I'm OK but what about member of a `union`:

```
union U{
    U(){std::cout << "U()\n";} // needed because a_'s class type has defined a user-defined version
    U(U const&){std::cout << "U(U const&)\n";} // needed as above
    ~U(){std::cout << "~U()\n";} // needed as above
    A a_; // has defined copy-control members
    int i_;
};

U u1;
U u2 = u1;
```

The output:

```
U()
U(U const&)
~U()
~U()
```

- So as you can see: the `union U` didn't initialize its member data `a_` and `i_` in its ctor-init-list nor those members have in-class initializers but non of their constructors was called! So:

Are member data of a `union` are default-initialized in the constructor initializer list? Thank you!

Comment: And which member constructor do you expect a `union` to call exactly? What if multiple union members are of types that have constructors defined? It can't initialize the same memory multiple times. Until a value is actually assigned to the `union`, it doesn't even know which member is active. In fact, until C++11, a union couldn't even hold a member that had a constructor defined. The correct way to deal with multiple types in the same memory in modern C++ is to use `std::variant` instead of a `union` whenever possible.

Comment: A union only has one valid member at a time. How are you expecting C++ to choose which to initialize? Initializing both would be a major problem if they were both class types, because the second initialization would be randomly stomping all over the memory previously written by the first initialization.

Comment: *How are you expecting C++ to choose which to initialize?* Telepathy, of course. We should have that worked out by C++8191.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So as you can see: the union U didn't initialize its member data a_ and i_

A union only ever has one member active, so there is never a case where two members could be initialised.

No member of a union initialised if you don't provide an initialiser in a user defined constructor.

Answer (score -1):

a union is just multiple names(references) for one location
no matter what member you modify, only one location is being addressed
thus all other members will be modified

```
union _Union{
    int i;      //  4 bytes.
    long ll;    //  4 bytes.
    float f;    //  4 bytes.
    char*txt;   //  4 bytes.
};

sizeof(_Union)  =   4 bytes
```

if struct the size would be 16 bytes
size of a union is the size of the largest member
if above `_Union` had another `long long int` member then its size would be 8 bytes
since `long long int` is 8

Comment: Stop using identifiers that begin with an underscore they may clash with the core language ones.